# Get the product of two one dimensional numpy matrices

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have two one-dimensional numpy matrices:

`[[ 0.69  0.41]]` and `[[ 0.81818182  0.18181818]]`

I want to multiply these two to get the result

`[[0.883, 0.117]]` (the result is normalized)

If I use `np.dot` I get `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I solved it in a kind of hacky way, but it worked for me, regardless of if there is a better solution or not.

```
new_matrix = np.matrix([ a[0,0] * b[0,0], a[0,1] * b[0,1] ])
```

Comment: You can't multiply two 1x2 matrices. You have to transpose one of them to get a 2x1 matrix. But then the result is either 2x2 or 1x1, not 1x2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: What do your arrays eventually look like? Maybe you can post the python output like `a = ...`

Comment: It's best to post runnable code that generates your problem, rather than incomplete snippets - see http://sscce.org/

Comment: The arrays looks exatcly as i posted when i print them like "print a"

Comment: Yes, but that's just [what `print` spits out](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), not code I/we can copy-paste and use to see your exact problem. It might sound lazy on my part, but I guarantee you'll get great answers straight away if you do that.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide any good overview over the code, but it would have been a lot to post to give you the overview. I'm pretty new here, so I guess I need a bit of exercise. I found a solution that worked for me needs (updated original post). Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you find your own solution to your own problem, you should post it as an answer.  If it's the best answer, select it with the green checkmark.

Comment: No worries. I didn't mean to sound harsh - sorry. Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to do element-wise math.  Numpy arrays do this by default.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.matrix([.69,.41])

In [3]: b = np.matrix([ 0.81818182, 0.18181818])

In [4]: np.asarray(a) * np.asarray(b)
Out[4]: array([[ 0.56454546,  0.07454545]])

In [5]: np.matrix(_)
Out[5]: matrix([[ 0.56454546,  0.07454545]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a little more pretty than what I did come up with!